# Connect to remote MSSQL server with PHP not working

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

I'm having problems connecting to the remote server using PHP Version is 7.3.5

```
<?php
        
   $serverName = "domain ipaddress";//<computer>\<instance name> 
   $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"databasename", "Uid"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");  
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
            
   if ($conn) {
      echo "connection was established";
   } else {
      echo "connection failed<br/>";
      die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
     
?>
```

Error messages are the following:

> Array ([0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456
> [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Login failed for user 'user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. )
> [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] =>
> 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Cannot open database "databasename" requested by the login. The
> login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "databasename" requested by
> the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE]
> => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. [message]
> => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1]
> => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "databasename" requested by
> the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "databasename"
> requested by the login. The login failed. ) )

Now the code works if I run it from WAMP server on my localhost and run the database also on my localhost via Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Then I can connect.

Comment: The error message is clear - the username and/or password are wrong. Does the remote SQL Server have an SQL login with name `user` and password `password`?

Comment: @Zhorov. Yes, the user name and password is correct, I have checked and double-checked. just to make sure. I can see that I'm getting a request to the server on the log but its denied. and that is all on the error message

Comment: Then does the database `databasename` exist in the remote server?

Comment: I think the databasename is more likely the issue - it wouldn't try to switch to that database unless it had already successfully authenticated the SQL login and password. Either the database doesn't exist on the server or the SQL login doesn't have a corresponding user mapping granting it access to that database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Correct, I'm able to reproduce the first scenario (existing SQL login and missing database), but probably permissions will be the reason for the error here.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the exact same error.

I was able to connect by removing the database parameter from the array, like so:

```
$server ="server_ip"; 
$username ="dbusername";
$password ="dbpassword";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $username, "PWD" => $password);
$link = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

if( $link === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Obviously that means it only works with a user that has a default database specified. I only need to connect to a single DB, so it's working for me. Not sure why specifying the database breaks it?